# Pointers and execution speed

Tags: c, pointers

Some blogs and sites were talking about pointers are beneficial one of the causes was because the "execution speed" will be better in a program with pointers than without pointers. The thing I can work out is that:

- Dereferencing a single location requires two (or more) memory accesses (depending on number of indirection). Which will increase the execution time, compared to if it was used directly.
- Passing a pointer to a large datatype to a function, like a structure can be beneficial, as only the address of the structure/union is getting copied and it's not getting passed by value. Therefore it should be faster in this case.

For example just by force introducing pointers without any need as:

```
int a, b, *p, *q, c, *d;
p = &a;
q = &b;
d = &c

// get values in a, b 

*d = *p + *q;  // why the heck this would be faster
c = a + b;     // than this code?
```

I checked the assembler output using `gcc -S -masm=intel file.c` The pointer version has a lot of loading memory and storing for the dereferences than the direct method.

Am I missing something?

*Note: The question is not related to just the code. The code is just an example. Not considering compiler optimizations.*

Comment: "Beneficial" or "better" can only be used comparing one thing with another. So the question is with what the author has compared the executin speed. Concerning passing structs vs. struct pointers, the pointers are faster - if the respective struct is not used heavily. Concerning other things, it greatly depends.

Comment: In the best case both versions are equivalent because the compiler can already dereference if the involved types are known. Try compiling your example with `-O2` and see how the pointers are optimized away.

Comment: Not considering compiler optimization, the main point of the question is if using pointers always increase execution speed for some "magical" reason? Or pointers should be thought as normal variables which hold an integer which we intend to use as a memory address, and by some syntax we tell the compiler identifiers we will be using to hold such values.

Comment: Not all textbooks make this claim. I have read (don't recall where) that consideration should be given whether to pass by reference of by value. For small data types your assumptions about indirection are right.

Comment: @Kenneth: ya that's the point. Definitely we can gain execution speed, if we use pointers wisely, but it is not that we will *always* gain speed.

Answer (score 6):

I think your conclusions are basically right. The author did not mean that using more pointers will always speed up all code. That's obviously nonsense.

But there are times when it is faster to pass a pointer to data instead of copying that data.

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out: *Passing a pointer to a large datatype to a function*; here the structure is an `int`, so it's hardly large. BTW: I guess gcc will optimize away the pointer accesses when you use -O2.

Apart from that your understanding is correct.

Comment: Not considering any kind of compiler optimization, it's just an example. Consider it is inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in your example - that code would run slower.  One place where it can be faster is when making a function call:

```
void foo( Object Obj );
void bar( const Object * pObj );

void main()
{
    Object theObject;
    foo( theObject );  //  Creates a copy of theObject which is then used in the function.
    bar( &theObject );  //  Creates a copy of the memory address only, then  the function references the original object within.
}
```

`bar` is faster as we don't need to copy the entire object (assuming the object is more than just a base data type).  Most people would use a reference rather than a pointer in this instance, however.

```
void foobar( const Object & Obj );
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark Byers is absolutely right. You cannot judge the power of pointers in such simple program.They are used to optimize the memory management and faster execution of programs where there are excessive use of data structures and references are done through addresses.
Consider when you start a program it takes some time in loading but with efficient use of pointers and skills if the program loads even 1 second earlier that's a large accomplishment.